# How to retrieve custom attributes in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I have defined some custom attributes and assigned them to products via the [Opencart](http://www.opencart.com/) admin panel.  I'm trying to retrieve these attributes upon checkout to adjust some shipping costs.

I'm currently working in the `catalog/model/shipping/ups.php` file in the `getQuote` function.  I'm getting close with this:

```
print_r($this->cart->getProducts());
```

Which gives me the following product data:

```
Array
(
    [59] => Array
        (
            [key] => 59
            [product_id] => 59
            [name] => My Product Name 
            [model] => ABC
            [shipping] => 1
            [image] => data/myproduct.jpg
            [option] => Array
                (
                )

            [download] => Array
                (
                )

            [quantity] => 1
            [minimum] => 1
            [subtract] => 1
            [stock] => 1
            [price] => 29.99
            [total] => 29.99
            [reward] => 0
            [points] => 0
            [tax_class_id] => 0
            [weight] => 3.75
            [weight_class_id] => 5
            [length] => 0.00
            [width] => 0.00
            [height] => 0.00
            [length_class_id] => 3
        )

)
```

However, no custom attributes are returned.  I'm sure there is a nice way to pass the product ID to an attribute-getting function, but I can't find it.  The Opencart docs are a little lacking for the development side and no luck on Google.

Usually I'd `grep` the hell out of the whole directory structure to find what I'm looking for, but shell access is disabled on this particular web host :(.

**EDIT**

I believe Attributes are a newer feature that is built into Opencart.  Its like a custom field.

Anyway, on the admin side I went to Catalog > Attributes and created a custom attribute called "Shipping Box Type".  Then, under a specific product I can set the attribute.  See screenshot.  My goal is to retrieve the value of "Shipping Box Type".  Does that answer your question @Cleverbot?  I'm sure I can do a custom db query to grab it, but theres got to be a built-in function to grab attributes?

[image: opencart product attributes]

Comment: What attribute names are you trying to pass?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Retrieve attributes for a given product_id**

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');

$attributes = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes(59); 

print_r($attributes);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [attribute_group_id] => 9
            [name] => Shipping Fields
            [attribute] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [attribute_id] => 16
                            [name] => Shipping Box Type
                            [text] => SM2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Taking it further, here is an example of looping through the products currently in the cart to see what attributes they have:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');

$cart_products = $this->cart->getProducts();

// get attributes for each product in the cart
foreach($cart_products as $product) {
    $attributes = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($product['product_id']);
    print_r($attributes);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most intuitive feature in Opencart. First you have to go catalog>attributes>attribute groups and you have to create a group name that will be a title for your attribute. For this it might be "Shipping Specifications".

Then you need to go to catalog>attributes>attributes> and create a new attribute under "Shipping Specifications" named "Shipping Box Type".

Now you are ready to go to catalog>products and add the attribute to a product.

**The catch** is that it won't be displayed how you were hoping I think. It will show up under the specifications tab next to description on your products page. You have the easy option of changing "Specifications" to the Heading of your choice in catalog/view/*your_theme*/products/products.tpl or you can edit the same tpl file to change the container/format that the data output goes.

Comment: thanks @Cleverbot.  This didn't answer it for me totally, but it helped me find the function I was looking for: `getProductAttributes`.  II'll post an answer with some actual code that I end up using.

Comment: Ah I see you wanted the function name and location. Well I'm glad you got it